# LINQ in Windows 8.1 Universal Apps

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, win-universal-app

I am using Windows 8.1 Universal Apps and I am placing my shared code in the Shared project.

I have a ViewModel which needs to call a LINQ method to reset a property to the first item in a list, here is the code.

```
public ObservableCollection<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
public Movie Current { get; set; }

...

public void Reset()
{
   this.Current = this.Movies.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

However it appears as though LINQ is not available in the Shared project and I cannot add a reference.

I can however, use LINQ in the Windows 8.1 and the Windows Phone 8.1 projects, therefore I can probably create a class in each and inherit from my ViewModel and implement this separately for each project. But this seems overkill for what I'm trying to achieve.

Can anyone rescue me?

Comment: What about: this.Movies.Item[0] ?  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms132434%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly and you want to reset **current** to point/refer to the first element in **Movies** collection, use:

```
this.current = this.Movies.Item[0];
```

See: [Collection.Item Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms132434%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: this.Movies[0] does work, however I will need to perform some error handling in the case when the list is empty. FirstOrDefault() is more of a convenience.

I know for certain that I will require LINQ elsewhere, but it isn't available in classes inside the Shared project.

Comment: @MikeEason, you can always check if Movies coleection is null, true? In my opinion at this moment, you don't need Linq.

Comment: `this.Current = null;

            if (this.Movies != null)
                if (this.Movies.Count > 0)
                    this.Current = this.Movies[0];`

This is perhaps the best method, however in the future I will be in need of LINQ select queries. The current example is only half of the issue.

Comment: @MikeEason, So, you'll need to write classes, to be able to cast from IEnumerable to Movie class. Cheers, Maciej

Answer (score 0):

I would do it that way. Since you can't include Linq into the shared library, you could make a class that uses that class and pass that

```
Class MovieViewModel
{
    private IEnumerable<Movie> _movie;

    // your sorting logic here
    this.Current = this.Movies.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Or create a static extension method that you can pass the collection to and sort them. That way you can call this with any viewmodel